# table and column name to store in dataset from joined sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, join, dataset

I have 3 tables, in an access database that I can't modify, to query using a left join like so

```
SELECT
  tbl_A.mID,
  tbl_A.data,
  tbl_B.data,
  tbl_C.data
FROM ((tbl_A
  LEFT JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_B.mID)
  LEFT JOIN tbl_C ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_C.mID)
ORDER BY tbl_A.mID
```

now i want to store the column names including the table names for their corresponding table in the left joins

```
   Dim i as integer = 0
    For Each column As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns
      Dim lst As New ListBox
      lst.name = "lst_" & i
      lst.add(new ColumnAndListBox(ds.Tables(0).TableName & "." & column.ColumnName, lst.name)
      i += 1
    next
```

the the result in that list should look like this

```
tbl_A.mID  lst
tbl_A.data lst
tbl_B.data lst
tbl_C.data lst
```

I need the complete name (table and column) to be able to dynamically create the where clause and query for example the mID because query like this doesn't work

```
SELECT
      tbl_A.mID,
      tbl_A.data,
      tbl_B.data,
      tbl_C.data
    FROM ((tbl_A
      LEFT JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_B.mID)
      LEFT JOIN tbl_C ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_C.mID)
    WHERE mID = 1
    ORDER BY tbl_A.mID
```

Comment: Which table's mID in where clause? WHERE tbl_A.mID = 1?

Comment: tbl_A.mID but because i generate the where clause dynamically over all three tables i can't add tbl_A for every column...that would result in tbl_A.data for all three over cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  tbl_A.mID,
  tbl_A.data,
  tbl_B.data,
  tbl_C.data
FROM ((tbl_A
  LEFT JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_B.mID)
  LEFT JOIN tbl_C ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_C.mID)
WHERE mID = 1
ORDER BY tbl_A.mID
```

won't work, but I think this will:

```
SELECT * from
  (
   SELECT
      tbl_A.mID,
      tbl_A.data adata,
      tbl_B.data bdata,
      tbl_C.data cdata
   FROM ((tbl_A
      LEFT JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_B.mID)
      LEFT JOIN tbl_C ON tbl_A.mID = tbl_C.mID)
   ORDER BY tbl_A.mID
   )     WHERE mID = 1
```